# OperationalError: near "(": syntax error" at SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

After taking a crash course for SQLite3, I tried to make a db for my first project:

```
import sqlite3 as db

conn = db.connect('todo.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE todo(id serial primary key, title text, created 
timestamp default now(), done boolean default 'f')")

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO todo (title) VALUES('Learn web.py')")
```

Unfortunately I receive this error:

> OperationalError: near "(": syntax error" at SQLite3

I do not understand what's wrong with the code. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), if the default value is not a simple value, it must be enclosed in parentheses:

```
CREATE TABLE todo(
    ...,
    created timestamp default (now()),
    done boolean default 'f'
);
```

(And `'f'` is not a valid value for a [boolean](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean_datatype). And `now()` is not an SQLite function.)